Can pthread_exit be used with noexcept functions?
I have a model where minimal work happens on main thread, and almost all work happens on worker threads. I want to ensure that the main thread NEVER dies and ALWAYS returns back to the OS.
Since, all my work is happening on worker threads, I want to kill the worker threads when some critical resource is not available. This allows me to efficiently write code without handling errors everywhere. For example, I require to allocate some memory on heap. I can invoke 'malloc' to do so, but 'malloc' may return nullptr, and instead of handling it every time I want to allocate memory, I simply want to kill the thread. Below is a sample code

void BlockMainThread () noexcept; // Wait on a semaphore
void ReleaseMainThread () noexcept; // Release the semaphore

int gExitStatus = 0;
bool gShouldRun = true;

[[noreturn]]
void
KillThread (int pExitStatus) noexcept
{
    gExitStatus = pExitStatus;

    ReleaseMainThread ();

    pthread_exit (nullptr); // Calls __forced_unwind internally
}

void *
Malloc (int pSize) noexcept
{
    void * ptr = malloc (pSize);

    if (!ptr)
        KillThread (1);

    return ptr;
}

void *
ThreadFunc (void *) noexcept // Executed by ALL worker threads
{
    printf ("Thread Started\n");

    while (gShouldRun) { // Do work till time to exit

        char * ptr = (char *) Malloc (100000);

        // Operate on ptr without needing to worry about ptr being NULL

        free (ptr);
    }

    return nullptr;
}

int
main ()
{
        pthread_t tid1;
        pthread_t tid2; // And so on

    pthread_create (&tid1, nullptr, ThreadFunc, nullptr); // And so on

    BlockMainThread ();

    gShouldRun = false; // Stop the loop on which threads are spinning

    pthread_join (tid1, nullptr); // Join with all threads

    if (gExitStatus == 0) // All was good
        return 0;

    // Else log a message depending on the gExitStatus

    printf ("Something went wrong");

    return gExitStatus;
}

All the functions are marked as noexcept, which means that none of the functions should ever do a throw. Else std::terminate will be invoked, and not allowing the main thread to return (which as stated earlier, is something I do NOT want to happen).
However, pthread_exit des a throw of 'abi::__forced_unwind' exception. And this exception is something that needs to be rethrown if caught (hence no point in catching it). And due to this, std::terminate is invoked (since my functions are noexcept). This prevents the main thread from logging what has gone wrong.
If the functions are NOT marked with noexcept, the thread unwinds and main thread will continue as expected.
This happens only on Linux OS. The same code does NOT throw the exception when used on Apple and Android Kernel.
Questions:

Is there something I can do to prevent std::terminate when pthread_exit is called within a noexcept function?
Can I use noexcept at all if I want to use this model?
Are there any platform-specific workarounds for Linux to mimic the behavior on Apple and Android?

Context and Considerations:

Platform Differences: On Linux, pthread_exit uses __forced_unwind for stack unwinding and cleanup, which throws an exception. This is not the case on Apple and Android, where pthread_exit does not involve throwing exceptions.
Exception Handling: The __forced_unwind exception is special and must propagate through stack frames without being caught, as catching it and not rethrowing can lead to undefined behavior.
Resource Management: The goal is to terminate worker threads cleanly without complicating error handling in every allocation or critical section.


Please explain what this has to do with Ubuntu?
